# What is the difference between Future and future?

Tags: scala, future

I am new to scala.In Future, I saw it used in two different way i.e Future and future.

Example:

```
val sayHello = Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    "hello"
  }
```

Similarly,

```
val sayHello = future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    "hello"
  }
```

But I didn't find any difference in Output. I will be pleased if anybody

makes it clear to me.

Comment: There is a `def future` which was part of `scala.concurrent` package object.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is the same thing indeed, and future (lowercase) is actually deprecated since 2.11.0.

See the actual code in scala lang: https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0/src/library/scala/concurrent/package.scala#L101